# Minecraft Server - Same Network -> Brother can't connect

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

We've been able to get this to work before but now that we've come back after a few months, my brother is no longer able to connect to my minecraft server.

I am not doing a LAN server because my cousins who live elsewhere want to play as well; all of them have been able to connect to my server using my local IP with no problems whatsoever.

Things you should know:

- We use a Windows 7 Wired Desktop Computer as the Host computer.
- We use a Belkin Router.
- My Brother's computer is a Laptop.

I think I've tried everything I found on the internet and it's getting frustrating because it just will not work! I also tried this:

- Port forwarding
- I've given my brother my IPV4 & Local IP address but none of that has worked.
- We've tried using port 25565 and without it host computer a DMZ but that had no luck as well.
- I've disabled firewalls from both ends and that hasn't worked either.

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: If your brother is on the same LAN as you and the server, then try connecting with the local IP of the server computer (192.168.x.x) instead of the public IP of the router - port-forwarding etc is all good for people from 'out in the world' connecting to the server on your LAN, but some routers have problems looping back internal traffic that reaches the world-facing address back into the LAN it came from. By using the local address you're bypassing the router part entirely, at most it serves as a dumb hub connecting the LAN computers together without any interaction with the Internet.

Comment: Do you use minecraft server, or do you yust use "open lan game" in a singleplayer Minecraft world?

Answer (score -1):

Well, if you are not using LAN than you need to port forward your IP. It is different depending on your router but I would suggest looking up a port forwarding tutorial. You just need to make sure that you use the correct IP when doing this. Once you have port forwarded you should be able to give your friends your public IP address. To figure this out just type in "my ip" in Google. Your friends should be able to connect once you do this.

Comment: I have portforwarded already

Comment: This really sounds like a blocking-port problem. With the Host PC, go to this site and use this IP number: http://whatismyipaddress.com/ He needs to connect to this IP. And you need to open the port (you specified in the server settings) in your router, otherwise it won't work. It's important to open the TCP and not the UDP port.

Answer (score -1):

Allow Java through your windows firewall (both the inbound and outbound connections) and you should be good. Do this on both computers.